# поиск по двум таблицам двумя способами?

Tags: sql

есть 1-ая таблица `movie (id, name, directorid, year)` и 2-ая `director (id, name)`.

Задача вывести список фильмов, снятых директором `‘Guy Ritchie’` одним запросом двумя способами.
Ну хорошо:

```sql
SELECT * FROM movie WHERE directorid = (SELECT id FROM director WHERE name = 'Guy Ritchie');
```

А второй способ какой, пожалуйста, подскажите?

Comment: через join склеить

Comment: Первый способ в общем случае неверен - хоть и подразумевается, но нигде явно не сказано, что `director.name` уникально.

Answer (score 2):

второй

```
SELECT movie.* FROM movie 
INNER JOIN director 
ON director.id = movie.directorid
WHERE director.name = 'Guy Ritchie';
```

Answer (score 0):

Использование объединений

```sql
select * 
from
    movie inner join director on movie.directorid = dorector.id
where
    director.name = 'Guy Ritchie';
```